# From Login page to tabs page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I’m trying to create my first app with Ionic Framework and I’m stuck. I want to have a login page before my tabs pages that is my main screen on my app and, I’m getting always same error of URL. Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs/tab1'

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [

  { 
    path: '', 
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' 
  },

  {
    path: 'tabs',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**tabs.router.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab1/tab1.module').then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab2/tab2.module').then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab3',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: () =>
              import('../tab3/tab3.module').then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

**login.page.ts**

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toTabs(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs')
  }

}
```

**login.page**

HTML file just have an ion-button linked to onClick event toTabs().

I’ve tryed to navigate to ‘/tabs’, to ‘/tabs/tab1’ and to ‘tabs’ and I desperated. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: Change ```path:'tabs'``` to ```path:''``` in your tabs routing module. You already declared the path in the upper app routing module. And also remove /tabs from the redirectTos in your tab routing module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default route back to the tabs module. If you want to show the tabbar in the app, place route under a tab in tabs.router.module.ts. If you don't want to show the tabbar, place the route in app-routing.module.ts.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule) },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginPageModule) }
]
```

You should make an AuthService where you save user details. You place a login function here, if user is found, set the user details in variable currentUser.
Now you can access the user in your app if you import this AuthService in other pages.

```js
export class AuthService {
  currentUser: User;

  // place access functions here
}
```

And in the entry point of your app: **app.component.ts**. Control if the user is set with user details. If so, go to the home page, if not, go to the login page.

```js
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {     
    this.authService.currentUser ? this.router.navigateByUrl('') :   this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm new in Ionic Framwork and I'm a little bit lost.